# Can I set onClickevents that are not yet defined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that looks like this:

```
const ProductCarousel = React.createClass({
  componentDidMount: function () {
    this.flky = new Flickity('.carousel', flickityOptions)
    //here
  },
  render: function () {
    const item = this.props.item
    return (
      <div>
        <div className='carousel'>
          {item.get('images').map((url, i) => (
            <img key={i.toString()} src={stripUrl(url)} width={520} />
          ))}
        </div>
        <div style={{marginTop: '20px', display: 'flex'}}>
          {item.get('images').map((url, index) =>
            <div style={{flexGrow: 1, margin: '0 1em 0 1em'}} className='hidden-xs' key={url}>
              <Thumbnail src={stripUrl(url)} />
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

the place where it says "here", I would like to define funcitons for `<Thumbnail onClick />`. Theese functions are methods for `this.flky`, so I can't create them before `componentDidMount`, but I would like to set them in the thumbnail and pass the thumbnails index to them. Is there something like a promise I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put it in a function, it won't get executed until it gets clicked, and the methods should exist by then:

```
 <Thumbnail src={stripUrl(url)} onClick={()=>this.flky.someMethod(index)} />
```

Comment: Cool, do I have to put the method inline like that or could I make an external reference?

Comment: You should be able to make it external, as long as the onclick function exists when it gets rendered.